# Pattern avoidance and P-recursiveness

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

A sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ is said to be *P-recursive* if there exist polynomials $p_0(n), p_1(n), \dots , p_k(n)$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k p_i(n) a_{n+i}=0
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Let $ P$ be a finite set of permutations in $S_k$ and $a_n(P)$ be the number of permutations in $S_n$ that do not contain any pattern in $P$. Noonan-Zeilbeger conjecture (1996) states that $\{a_n(P)\}_{n \geq 0}$ is P-recursive. Here we say that a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ contains a pattern $\tau \in S_k$ if there is a sequence $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n$ such that the numbers in the sequence $\pi(i_1), \dots, \pi(i_k)$ are in the same relative order as in $\tau(1), \dots, \tau(k)$. The Noonan-Zeilbeger conjecture was disproved by [Garrabrant and Pak (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.06508.pdf).

It is also conjectured in [Gessel (1990)](https://peeps.unet.brandeis.edu/%7Egessel/homepage/papers/dfin.pdf) that the problem of counting $k$-regular graphs with vertices $1, \dots, n$ and with a specified set of forbidden subgraphs is P-recursive in $n$. After some Google search it seems to me that this problem is still open. What are some progress that has been made since the paper of Gessel? How probable is this conjecture to be correct?

Comment: I don't think Gessel conjectured that.  He did discuss that problem (bottom of page 26) and suggested that "likely that new techniques will be necessary to deal with the general case."  I say this is a very weak endorsement.